# In MCSE/MCITP or i mean As Network Admin do i need to do SQL server or not

Tags: sql-server

In managing the servers (AD etc) do i ever need to do something which require sql server 2008 to do jobs.

Or SQL server is only required for websites or .NET applications only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a really difficult question to answer.  Really depends on the company that you are working for, what they do, size of the company, technologies they use.

For the most part, sysadmins are often a jack of all trades and dealing with databases is just part and parcel of the job.

Edit: That said though, if you're strictly looking to be a network admin vs systems admin then you are unlikely to need to know anything about MSSQL.

Comment: +1. I've worked in places where the sysadmin is also part time DBA and I've also worked in places where the sysadmin has no rights to DB servers/services at all. It depends.

Comment: WIth regard to DBA what application uses the MS SQL database. I usually do mysql and use with webisites build in PHP.So i want to know only websites uses database or any other application

Comment: WSUS, SCOM, WSS, MOSS, MSCRM to name a few MS products

Answer (score 0):

In relation to the MCITP Server Administrator and Enterprise Administrator certification paths, you do need to know some basic things about SQL Server. Such as what kind of RAID would suit. You should know about shared storage options, such as SAN's & iSCSI & the requirements for basic HA setup, i.e. shared storage + MS clustering.  You'll also need to be aware of the basic functionality of SCOM. What MOSS & WSS are & when you would use one over the other.

It's all part of making sure you know how to operate within the Mircosoft family :-)